# Date based select query not working inside cursor

Tags: oracle, plsql, cursor

I am working on a stored procedure which has the following date based select query inside cursor like below

```
CURSOR inv_cur ( v_hotel_id IN NUMBER, v_stay_date IN DATE)
  IS
    SELECT id,
      start_date ,
      room_count ,
      booked_room_count
    FROM inventory
    WHERE hotel_id          = v_hotel_id
    AND TRUNC( start_date ) = TRUNC(v_stay_date);
```

For some reason it does not work and I am not getting records. But when i execute without the date comparison or execute the query in the stand alone manner like below, it works

```
SELECT id,
      start_date ,
      room_count ,
      booked_room_count
    FROM inventory
    WHERE hotel_id          = 1509622
    AND TRUNC( start_date ) = TO_DATE('08-03-18', 'dd-mm-yy');
```

This is how I am invoking the cursor call

```
    PROCEDURE (.....)
     IS
     v_date_temp DATE;
     BEGIN
    v_date_temp          := p_check_in_date;
     FOR inventory_rec IN inv_cur
        (
          v_hotel_id, v_room_type_id, v_date_temp
        )
LOOP
      v_room_count      := inventory_rec.room_count;
      v_book_room_count := NVL ( inventory_rec.booked_room_count,0 );
      v_inventory_id    := inventory_rec.id;
      dbms_output.put_line(' Inv id' || v_inventory_id);
    END LOOP;
```

Since there are no records returned, it is not going inside loop.
I think there is something wrong with the date comparison. Can someone help me figure out this puzzling issue with my date comparison ?

Comment: Is V_STAY_DATE value known before opening the cursor?

Comment: I am passing it to the cursor. I am calling the cursor like below FOR inventory_rec IN inv_cur (
      v_hotel_id, v_date_temp
    )

Comment: @Littlefoot Yes it is known

Comment: You should include that in your question - and how `v_date_temp` is defined and populated.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "it does not work." Do you get any errors, or does it just not return any rows, when you call your procedure with the same values as the direct query? If so, it is likely related to how you assign a value to `v_stay_date` before you pass it in.

Comment: There are no errors just that it doesn’t return any rows

Comment: They already told you but the error probably is in the way you assign a value to `v_stay_date`. Can you debug your code? Can you find out the value that `v_stay_date` really has?

Comment: @AlexPoole I have done that

Comment: A step further: does P_CHECK_IN_DATE have a value? What is its datatype? How exactly do you pass its value to a procedure? Are you sure that it is a culprit? What about another cursor parameter, V_HOTEL_ID? Could you edit your message and post the way you call the procedure, along with its parameters?

Comment: Rather than `PROCEDURE (.....)`, don't you think the actual parameters and their values at runtime might be important? The whole issue seems to be about `p_check_in_date` which you are not showing us.